# Finding the sample at the beginning of a period of a compound periodic signal

Tags: c, signal-processing

I have a signal made up of the sum of a number of sine waves.  These are spaced at 100Hz, with the lowest component frequency at 200Hz (200Hz, 300Hz...etc.)  All component sine waves begin at the same point with phase = 0.  In my DSP software, where I am going to multiply this signal by several other signals, I need to find a point at which all of the original signal's component signals are all again at phase = 0.

If I were only using one sine wave, I could simply look for a change in sign from negative to positive.  However, if the signal has, say, components at 200Hz and 300Hz, there are three zero-crossing where the sign changes from negative to positive, but only one that represents the beginning of the period, and this increases with more component waves.  I do have control over the amplitudes of each component frequency during an initial startup sequence.  If these waves were strictly harmonic (200Hz, 400Hz, 800Hz, etc.), I could simply remove all but the lowest frequency, find the beginning of its period, and use this as my zero-sample.  However, I don't have this bandwidth.  Can anyone provide an alternative approach?

#### Edit:

(I have clarified and integrated this edit into body of question.)

#### Edit 2:

This graphic should demonstrate the issue.  The frequencies two components here are n and 3n/2.  Without filtering out all but the lowest frequency, or taking an FFT as proposed by @hotpaw, an algorithm that only looks for zero-crossings where the sign changes from negative positive will land on one of three, and I must find the first of those three (this is the one point at which each component signal is at phase = 0).  I realise that taking an FFT will work, but I'm dealing with very limited processing power and wondering if there's a simpler approach.

[image: Sample waveform]

Comment: Define "the beginning of the period".

Comment: What do you mean by "the beginning of its period"?  If it is periodic, it doesn't matter where you start it.

Comment: use a notch filter to look only at the frequency you want, then look for the sign crossing.  You can then match this point in time to your original signal.

Comment: @Joseph I think you mean a low-pass or band-pass filter (notch filter would leave everything except the desired frequency).  Also, trying to determine an exact point in time is a little tricky since the filter introduces delay.

Comment: @Jim My mistake, I did mean band-pass filter.  Accounting for the filter delay is indeed a challenge.

Comment: Maybe it is only me, but I find your setup hard to understand. Could you explain in more detail what exactly you measure? You have certain waves and some information on their periodicity through their hertz range. You get the sum of their signals. Among others, why would a sign change matter? Do they all start at the same moment? Last for the same time period? Then you mention control of amplitude. I'm no expert in this particular question, but a math geek and find myself puzzled to even well-define the question.

Comment: @Jim,Joseph: Determining the group delay of a filter is not tricky (assuming you have its coefficients).

Comment: Do you know anything about the relative phase of the various components ? Is the phase relationship arbitrary or do all the components have some common phase reference ?

Comment: @Paul, Φ is zero for all components.

Comment: @GarlicFries: you mean phase = 0 for all components at some initial reference point, e.g. t = 0 ? In that case it should be pretty trivial, assuming the phase relationship doesn't ever change.

Comment: @Paul, yes, that's what I mean.  It's not so trivial, though (that I can tell).  I'm adding a graphic to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the derivative of the signal!

Your signal is a sum of sines (sorry, I'm not sure how to format formulas properly)

`S = sum(a_n * sin(k_n * t)) ... over all n`

a_n is the positive amplitude and k_n the positive frequency. The derivative (that you can compute easily numerically) of the signal is

`dS/dt = sum(a_n * k_n * cos(k_n * t)) ... over all n`

At t=0 (what you're looking for), the derivative has its maximum since all cosine terms are one at the same time.

Some addition:
For the practical implementation you need to consider that the derivative may be noisy, so some kind of simple first-order filtering could be necessary.

Comment: I figured this would be the answer, as the only difference in those three zero-crossings is the slope.  Derivative it is, I guess!  Will have a go and report back.

Comment: Question--`A_n` is the instantaneous amplitude at time `t` for frequency `k_n`, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... `a_n` is the constant (maximum) amplitude of frequency `k_n`. The instantaneous amplitude at time `t` is `a_n * sin(k_n * t)` of course.

Comment: Sorry about my miscommunication.  The problem is that I don't know `t`--I only know `S`.  Is then the only way to do this to find the derivative 'by hand' by calculating the change in `S` at each sample?

Comment: Yes, but that's a cheap operation, only one difference per sample.

Comment: Right. Just for my own peace of mind--there's no way to find the derivative otherwise without knowing `t`, correct?

Comment: Yes, in your application, you have to calculate the derivative numerically. I added the analytical formula for the derivative in my answer only to prove that my suggestion of using it for your problem is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all the sine waves are exact harmonics of some fundamental frequency, all have a phase of zero with respect to the same reference point at some point in time, and that this is the point in time you wish to find.

You can use an FFT with an aperture length that is an exact multiple of the period of your fundamental frequency (100 Hz).  If there is zero noise, you can use 1 period.  Estimate the phase with respect to some reference point (FFT aperture start or center) of all the sinusoids using the FFT.  Then use the phase of the lowest frequency sinusoid that shows up as significant in the FFT to calculate all its zero crossings in your target time range.  Compare with the nearest zero crossing of all the other sinusoids (using the FFT phase to estimate their phases), and find the low frequency zero crossing with the total least squared error of offsets from all the nearest zero crossings of all the other frequencies.

You can go back to the time domain to confirm the least squares estimated crossing as an actual zero crossing and/or to remove some of the numerical noise.

Comment: +1: This also assumes that the period of the sine waves is an exact multiple of the sampling period.

Comment: Also, if there's no noise, it should be sufficient to find the phase of the 200 and 300Hz components.

Comment: Yes, they all waves are exact harmonics of some fundamental frequency (though it is not present in the signal).  But no, the period of the sine waves is not an exact multiple of the sampling period--this I cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a first or second order lowpass filter to remove the component frequencies. The difference between 100 Hz and the "noise" makes quite a wide gap. Start with a low frequency that cancels all noise and increase until you are satisfied with the signal.

After that you have your signal and can watch for the sign change.

Second order implementation:

```
 static float a1 = 0;
 static float a2 = 0;
 static float b1 = 0;
 static float b2 = 0;

 static float y = 0;
 static float y_old = 0;
 static float u_old = 0;

 void
 init_lp_filter(float cutoff_freq, float sample_time) 
 {
   float wc = cutoff_freq;
   float h = sample_time;

   float epsilon = 1.0f/sqrt(2.0f);
   float omega = wc * sqrt(0.5f);
   float alpha = exp(-epsilon*wc*h);
   float beta = cos(omega*h);
   float gamma = sin(omega*h);

   b1 = 1.0f - alpha * (beta + epsilon * wc * gamma / omega);
   b2 = alpha * alpha + alpha * (epsilon * wc * gamma / omega - beta);
   a1 = -2.0f * alpha * beta;
   a2 = alpha * alpha;
 }

 float
 getOutput() {
   return y;
 }

 void
 update_filter(float input)
 {
   float tmp = y;
   y = b1 * input + b2 * u_old - a1 * y - a2 * y_old;
   y_old = tmp;
   u_old = input;
 }
```

As the filtered output depends only on old values, this means that the filtered output can be used direct at the beginning of a cycle. The filter can then be updated at the end of the periodic cycle with a sample of measurement. Do note that if you have any output that may affect the signal (i.e. actuators on a physical process), you must sample the signal before any output.)

Good luck!

Comment: I do have control over the amplitude of the component frequencies during this sync process, so there is no need to lowpass filter the composite signal.  Am I missing some then, or is this as easy as using the actual 'fundamental' frequency (100Hz) for my startup sequence, and once synced removing this component and adding all higher harmonics?

Comment: It sounds that way but I'm not sure that I understand the question after the two edits. Can you perhaps clarify your objective?