# How can down-sampling periodic time-series data without loosing general pattern for characterization analysis?

Tags: python, time-series, fft, resampling, periodic-processing

I'm experimenting with the characterization of data over time after downsampling. After studying this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060619/10452700), I generated some synthesized data with certain periodic patterns over time every 5mins (granularity of 5mins= data generated with the interval of 5 mins). It means that for each hour I generate 12 observations and at the end of the day (24hrs) I have 12*24 = 288 observations\data points over time. I generated the PWM data pattern with a certain period. I could generate other patterns i.e. *Positive Triangle Pulse*, *Positive Pulses (Rectangles)*, *Impulses*,... but I picked PWM for a better understanding of changes in behavior.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate periodic data : PWM Modulated Sinusoidal Signal
# Set the duty cycle percentage for PWM
percent = 40.0
# Set the time period for one cycle of the PWM signal
TimePeriod = 6.0
# Set the desired number of samples
desired_samples = 278
# Calculate the time step (dt) to achieve the desired number of samples
# 30 is the original number of cycles in the provided code
dt = TimePeriod / (desired_samples / 30)
# Calculate the number of cycles needed to achieve the desired number of samples
Cycles = int(desired_samples * dt / TimePeriod) + 1
# Create a time array
t = np.arange(0, Cycles * TimePeriod, dt)
# Generate a PWM signal
pwm = (t % TimePeriod) < (TimePeriod * percent / 100)
# Create a sinusoidal signal
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, len(pwm))
y_pwm = np.sin(x)
# Zero out the sinusoidal signal where PWM is zero
y_pwm[pwm == 0] = 0

# Convert data to a Pandas DataFrame
data = {'datetime': t_num, "PWM":y_pwm}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.shape #(288, 2)
```

So now I have a univariate time series including timestamp `datetime` and some periodic values in form of `PWM` signal.

Before downsampling, I made sure about datetime column by using:

- `df.datetime = pd.to_timedelta(df.datetime, unit='T')` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886911/10452700)
- `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74302888/10452700)

Then I applied [`resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to downsample *5mins to 1hour* like this post.

```py
resampled_df = (df.set_index('datetime')          # Conform data by setting a datetime column as dataframe index needed for resample
                  .resample('1H')                 # resample with frequency of 1 hour
                  .mean()                         # used mean() to aggregate
                  .interpolate()                  # filling NaNs and missing values [just in case] 
                )
resampled_df.shape                                # (24, 1)
```

another way inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71253512/10452700)

```py
resampled_df2 = (df.set_index('datetime')                   # Conform data by setting a datetime column as dataframe index needed for resample
                  .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1H')])         # resample with frequency of 1 hour
                  .mean()                                   # used mean() to aggregate
                 )

resampled_df2.shape                                         # (24, 1)
```

I used `mean()` method because I think average of each 12 observations within each hour could be good representative of behavior and has less negative impact on behavior for *Periodic Patterns\behavior Identification*.

Now I want to demonstrate raw periodic data and resampled version:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))

#  PWM
axes[0].plot(   df['datetime'],  df['PWM'], color='blue')
axes[0].scatter(df['datetime'],  df['PWM'], color='blue', marker='o', s=10)
axes[0].set_title(f'PWM incl. {len(df)} observations')

# Resample of PWM
axes[1].plot(   resampled_df.index,  resampled_df['PWM'], color='blue')
axes[1].scatter(resampled_df.index,  resampled_df['PWM'], color='blue', marker='o', s=10)
axes[1].set_title(f'PWM (resampled frequency=1H) incl. {len(resampled_df)} observations')

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xticks(selected_ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(selected_ticks, rotation=90)


plt.show()
```

---

Output:
[image: img]

My objective is to **detect periodic/cyclic behavior** for further *characterization of data over time* but sometimes potential (nearly) periodic patterns can be seen in different data resolutions and one needs to downsample also because of volume of (big-)data. So I'm looking for best practices to downsample and detect periodic/cyclic behavior or potentially (nearly) periodic patterns.

I find the approach [Averaging periodic data with a variable sampling rate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43393945/10452700) but I'm not sure if fits my problem.

The closest workaround I have found so far is [*How to decompose multiple periodicities present in the data without specifying the period?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71876632/10452700). Another thing is always people propose FFT to see possible patterns instead of time-domain in frequency-domain but there are some discussion which state:

> *The FFT is the **wrong** tool to use for finding the periodicity. ...* [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4242450/10452700)

If FFT or DFT approaches are useful what is the best practice to set sampling frequency for PWM I have generated according to `sample_freq=n_samples/(tmax-tmin)` which should reflect periodicity by `sample_preiod=1/sample_freq` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66863541/10452700).

Please note that I'm not interested in this solution such as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69383550/10452700) using `.iloc` because I believe  *(de-)selecting by position* would ruin the periodic patterns of data.

I also I'm aware of some facts like:

> 1. *"Downsampling always means a loss of information, which is why in general downsampling is preferably avoided."* [ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713037/10452700)
>    following picture from my own experiments for the showcase:
>    [image: img]
> 2. *"...down sample how much of data observations..."* [ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660461/10452700)

---

Time-series:

- [Downsampling time series data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73221445/10452700)
- [Downsample non timeseries pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72167661/10452700)
- [How to convert data into time series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74302888/10452700)
- [Convert Pandas dataframe to time series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915420/10452700)
- [Resample DataFrame at certain time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049200/10452700)

Signal processing:

- [Signal Processing: Sample rate vs sample period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66863541/10452700)
- [Finding the sample at the beginning of a period of a compound periodic signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150168/10452700)
- [how to find out the period of a signal based on its autocorrelation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509639/10452700)
- [Periodic Patterns Identification in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919920/10452700)

Comment: apply Kalman filtering before sampling

Comment: I will check it out. Do you think is there a Pythonic package I or you could apply to I generated data I proposed in question and see if it has a positive impact before sampling? Can you elaborate further on why the Kalman filter could have a positive impact before sampling and keeping characteristics of data and help periodic behavior detection?